# Which site would be appropriate to get input on law-related software ideas?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a problem that I really want to solve which concerns almost every society -
 preventing wrongful convictions. Since I'm a developer, I want to see if there's anything I can develop that might help mitigate this problem.

Would I post this question in a software-related Stack Exchange site or law-related Stack Exhange site, and which one?

Comment: That question sounds way too broad and also too opinion based for any SE site.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have a deep understanding of the problem before you can even begin to think about writing code as a solution (or mitigation). If you can formulate *specific* and *detailed* questions that are *not* matters of opinion, [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) *might* be a good place to ask.

**I would, however, recommend that before you start posting questions, find lawyers who have been involved in criminal law for the jurisdiction you are interested in, and sit down and discuss the issue with them. You will need to speak to more than one, if for no other reason than you will need to see the issue from both the prosecution and defense points of view.**

Consider also that every time you cross a border, whether municipal, state/provincial/district, or national, jurisdiction and law *changes*, and you will likely need to customize any eventual solution to each jurisdiction in which it will be used. This is not - and probably cannot be - a simple problem to solve, or even to mitigate, and while your desire may be laudable, it is very likely neither practical nor attainable in any meaningful way.

I also believe, as a technically-oriented person in regular contact with a local law enforcement establishment, that you will find that there will be very little that you can do with software for your proposed marketplace that isn’t already being done.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to see if there's anything I can develop that might help mitigate this problem.

Without knowing the actual question you're proposing, I'm speculating that (at this early stage) your question may be too broad for *any* Stack Exchange site. Questions are generally expected to contain a very specific problem statement about where you're stuck in your work specifically… something that can be definitively resolved in the space of a post. So asking broadly, *"Is there anything I can develop to solve {x}"* would likely be a bit too early for a Stack Exchange-style Q&A. I would suggest entering into such collaborations in a general discussion forum — they're a better fit for that type of collaboration.

**But setting that aside for a second…**

If you're looking to overcome a *specific* hurdle you've encounter in your project, consider the domain of the actual problem. **Which community has the *expertise* to answer it?** If you're trying to solve a programming problem (regardless of what the program is actually about), Stack Overflow ([or  one of our programming-related sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)) is probably the best place to start. If someone with a legal background would be more apt, then [Law SE](https://law.stackexcahnge.com) is a better choice.